# How to store chars like  into MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

The test script as below:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( title varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO test (title) value ('');
```

The response says:

```
1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\x89\xF0\x9F...' for column 'title' at row 1.
```

I try to set the `CHARSET` to `utf8`, `utf16`, `gbk` but the responses are the same.

I don't know what to call these chars '' and type them out using keyboard. But they are different with '♥☆',which can be store in charset `utf8`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the column type as BINARY or VARBINARY.

Answer (score 0):

your value saved as binary so you can change the data type of your column `title` to be `blob`.

Answer (score 0):

`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is needed for Emoji and some Chinese characters.  `utf8` will not suffice.